# Vaadin shows "Message: Object doesn't support this property or method" with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, vaadin

Whenever I compile a Widgetset with Vaadin 6.5.6 or 6.5.7 in Eclipse and then run the application it only works in firefox and safari. IE always gives :

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Fri, 29 Apr 2011 16:45:28 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 2860
Char: 445
Code: 0
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8080/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.example.newvaadin9.widgetset.Newvaadin9Widgetset/6F6CE40261565705783015CF405E65E8.cache.html
```

:upon loading. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for IE9 is added with Vaadin 6.6. Pre-release was released yesterday with final targeted to be released in two weeks. Please upgrade.

Comment: As an aside I have tried to get Vaadin touchkit to build an iphone webapp working on my iphone but I have had to severly hack mobile-style.css and I still can't seem to get it right. Is there a working version of this style sheet in a repository somewhere?